# Issue with fopen and fwrite PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm having issues writing to the file VarLog.txt, It's not read only (In properties), I'm trying to write the Variable or SQL Query as a string in the logs file that I created, I also wrote a check to see if VarLog exists, and if it doesn't, make it. Here's the Code

```
   if (!file_exists( "VarLog.txt")) {
    $fh = fopen("VarLog.txt", 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fclose($fh);
}
function anti_injection($sql) {
   $fp = fopen("VarLog.txt", "a+");  
   $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$sql);
   $sql = trim($sql);
   $sql = strip_tags($sql);
   $sql = addslashes($sql);
   fwrite($fp, "SQL Query/String: $sql"); 
   fclose($fp);
   return $sql;
}
```

An Example of a $_POST variable

```
anti_injection($_POST['email']);
```

Comment: Could you please describe the issues you are experiencing?

Comment: @iWizardPro - Nothing is being written to the VarLog.txt file even when I have all my $_POST variables as `anti_injection($_POST['email']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself doesn't present any errors, other than the first check if the file exists and creating it is redundant.

1. Remove the file VarLog.txt if it exists to rule out ownership problems.
2. Check what your working directory is. Your path right now isn't an absolute path, so files will be written relative to whatever the current working directory is (use `getcwd()` to find out what that path is, and check there).

Comment: Hmm... I did the `getcwd()` and got my wwwroot, I pasted it into `$fp = fopen("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VarLog.txt", "a+");`

The file still isn't being created :( @iWizardPro

Comment: You need to escape the slashes. `$fp = fopen("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\VarLog.txt", "a+");`

Comment: I tried that, and still nothing is being written, I check permissions and admins have full control on my VPS, I assume PHP is counted as an administrator? Also we are using windows server 2008

Comment: To debug this further, add a `print_r(error_get_last());` following the `$fp = fopen(...);` line.

Comment: `Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => fopen(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VarLog.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied [file] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Player_Panel\login.php [line] => 99 )` I Guess it is an issue with the permissions, i'll ask the server owner about it. Thanks :) @iWizardPro - Upvoted